# modern cv: line distance letterclosing and cover letter

Tags: moderncv

Moderncv, cover letter: Does anybody know how to diminish for the distance the letter's main part and the "Kind regards,"-line? Though I'm using the xpatch-package for the letterclosing it's not working correctly. On the other hand, for the letteropening it's no problem at all.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %notwendig für eingescannte Unterschrift.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %notwendig für die Darstellung des Datums in deutscher Weise.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

%------------------

\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}
\birthdate{Birthday}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipie‌​ntname}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\@opening\\[1.5em]}{\@opening\\[.1em]}{}{} \xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company}{Street\\ City}
\date{\today}

\opening{To who it may concern:}
\closing{Kind regards,}

\makelettertitle

%------------------------------

Hello

%----------Schlussformel-------

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, the command to be patched is no more `\makelettertitle` but `\makeletterhead`, so the correct patch for this version is

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterhead}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipientname}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterhead}{\@opening\\[1.5em]}{\@opening\\[.1em]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\vspace*{-.5em}\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
\makeatother
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

Adding the line

```
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\vspace*{-.5em}\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
```

in your preamble (adjust `-.5em` to your needs) and removing

```
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
```

does what you want.

To apply the patch, since you have some spurious characters in your code, I suggest you to delete the lines

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipie‌​ntname}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\@opening\\[1.5em]}{\@opening\\[.1em]}{}{} \xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
\makeatother
```

and replace them with

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipientname}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\@opening\\[1.5em]}{\@opening\\[.1em]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\vspace*{-.5em}\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %notwendig für eingescannte Unterschrift.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %notwendig für die Darstellung des Datums in deutscher Weise.



\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

%------------------

\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}
\birthdate{Birthday}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipientname}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\@opening\\[1.5em]}{\@opening\\[.1em]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\@closing\\[3em]}{\vspace*{-.5em}\@closing\\[.5em]}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company}{Street\\ City}
\date{\today}

\opening{To who it may concern:}
\closing{Kind regards,}

\makelettertitle

%------------------------------

Hello

%----------Schlussformel-------

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mmmm, for me it's not working at all. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Phil Do you want to reduce the spacing between 'Hello' and 'Kind regards' or what?

Comment: exactly, that's what I would like to do.

Comment: @Phil Take a look at the edited answer

Comment: I don't know what's the problem but it's not working at all. it's probably not about the code?!

Comment: @Phil Try copying the whole code in my answer in a new document and see if it works.